# I get date time format in json. How i bind date only in angular

Tags: angular

**I am getting this format JSON. How I am bind date only in angular8.**

Date :"2014-12-10T14:20:33.369000Z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this `| date` after the value in html

```
{{ Date | date }}
```